# Hide a Component from Visual Studio Windows Forms designer

Tags: visual-studio, components, hide

I'm just about to develop a custom component in Visual Studio 2010. In contrast to controls components are not visible during runtime and in design time they are shown in a component panel at the bottom of the designer window.

My custom component is able to create other components so that the created components are linked to my custom component. As I can create a lot of new components I would like to hide them from the component panel as I can access them via my custom control.

Is it possible to programmatically (or at all) hide components from the component panel?

Comment: If seems possibe that the components are hidden when the class ist attributed with [DesignTimeVisible(false)] but the component ist sealed. :-( Is there a different way??

Comment: There's just no point in making these 'other components' inherit from Component.  That class does *very* little, only the Site property is interesting.  You don't want that so just don't inherit from Component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the options of the component. There are a few options to hide the objects, make them available and more. To check the options just click the `component` + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: I believe he means to hide it when you are designing the form. Not when the app starts.