# Hiding data components tab in winforms design view in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I want to hide the tab showing all the data components (data sets, binding source, table adapters) at the bottom of my design view for winforms. Unlike all the other tabs it doesn't have the typical controls which allow closing it, only thing I can do is to bring it to minimal height.

It doesn't seem to be referred to by any of the options in the view tabs. Is there a way to hide it?

[Tab in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IZHS.png)

Edit:
Side question: What is the proper name of that tab?

Comment: According to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942487/hide-a-component-from-visual-studio-windows-forms-designer
it is rather impossible.

Comment: I believe that proper name is Component Container